# Dynamic Multiplication in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns where first columns containing initial 5 consecutive zeros and then followed by non zeros numbers.

What i want to achieve here is whenever nonzeros number are starting in the first column (which is in our example starting from cell number **A7** ) it should start multiply with the initial number of the second column. So in our example it should be (A7*B1) then (A8*B2) and so on and so forth..


Below is the screenshot for reference.

[image]

I tried with Below formula but its seems its doesn't server the purpose.

**`=IF(A2=0,0,A2*B2)`**

Would be really helpful if anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: If its 0 then it should remain 0 , but if its not then it should start multiplying with the first cell of multiplier column and continue the same.

Comment: `0` multiplied by anything is `0` why not just do `=A2*B2` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX` and `COUNTIF` function combination can help you:

```
=A2*INDEX($B$2:$B$10,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,">0"))
```

[image]

Comment: this would work only if there are no "0" after the intial ones but this should be the case according to the problem description

Comment: @akasolace thank you for your answer but yes there are few lines where numbers are follow by 0 again.
Could you tweak little in this formula to work with that as well.

Comment: How do you know which zeros to count and which to skip?

Comment: @basic All the zeros should Skip regardless of its order.

Comment: @JiteshVacheta Can you add some example in question with non initial zeros and show the desired result? And will there always be five zeros at the beginning or the numbers may vary?